# Find out if nested class is zero

Tags: c#

I have a class "Data" and a subclass "SubData". I want to access a method in SubData.

In order to do something like:

```
value = Data.SubData.getValue();
```

I need to make sure that Data!=null and also that SubData!=null.

I would usually do this:

```
if (Data!=null)
{
   if (Data.SubData!=null)
   {
       value=Data.SubData.Value();
   }
}
```

However when I want to print a message in case of Data or SubData being null, I need to put the message in two places:

```
if (Data!=null)
{
   if (Data.SubData!=null)
   {
       value=Data.SubData.Value();
   }
   else
   {
       // MESSAGE
   }  
}
else
{
    // MESSAGE
}
```

Is there a way of having //Message only in one place? Of course I could set a "showMessage flag" to true and then later have the message appear only in one place, but then I would still set the flag in two places.

Comment: More like a standard programming question than a testing related one ?

Comment: Well, it is about good style, I think. Which stackexchange forum would you move it to?

Comment: @Sebastian, try at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dzieciou, thank you! Seems like the perfect place for a question like the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the not null tests into one if statement

```
if (Data != null || Data.SubData != null)
{
    //Do Whatever
}
else
{
    //Message Evaluation Example
    return Data = null ? "Data is null!" : "Data.SubData is null!";
}
```

Above I have made a check on both Data and Data.SubData to ensure they are not null, if they are however I use a [Ternary Operator](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary) to figure out which is null and return the result as a string (don't know what data type you would like to return).

This assumes that both properties will never be null, if they are simply expand the evaluation code.

Comment: Can I be sure that Data!=null is tested for before Data.SubData!=null? It seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: Depends what you are after, but in my sample code yes you can be, as it would evaluate left to right. [Short-circuiting In If Statement Evaluations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877685/order-of-operators-in-if-statement), [Post From MSDN Forums On If Statement Evaluation Order](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/f772e6ea-004b-4e1c-b1e9-f10c8f60d9d8/)

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I was after. I just wasn't aware of the term "short circuiting". I'll accept your answer.